# nyx - Unable to connect to tor. Maybe it's running without a ControlPort?

Tags: onion-services, tor-install, nyx

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 server, headless and installed tor using the [debian instructions on the tor project](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en). However, nyx will not run to show me tor connection information, when I enter `nyx` I receive the message: `Unable to connect to tor. Maybe it's running without a ControlPort?`

However, I can see tor running when I run `top`.

```
   921 root      20   0   75448  19400   6356 S   0.3  0.5   0:03.12 tor
```

But, when I run `systemctl | grep tor` I see:

```
● tor.service            loaded active exited    Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)                  
● tor@default.service    loaded failed failed    Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
```

I've configured my 'tor service' in `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc` and that file's contents are:

```
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
PidFile /run/tor/tor.pid
RunAsDaemon 1
User debian-tor

ControlSocket /run/tor/control GroupWritable RelaxDirModeCheck
ControlSocketsGroupWritable 1
SocksPort unix:/run/tor/socks WorldWritable
SocksPort 9050

ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
CookieAuthFile /run/tor/control.authcookie

Log notice syslog
```

Any help to get nyx working and improve my tor implementation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833021/could-not-bind-to-127-0-0-19050-address-already-in-use-is-tor-already-running#834333) the issue was that another tor service was running, blocking access to the control port. The following code fixed the problem:

`sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep 9050`

To find the other service hogging the control port.

`sudo killall tor`

To kill all tor processes.

`sudo systemctl start tor.service`

Then I ran `journalctl -xe` to make sure that tor booted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u debian-tor nyx
```

[Solution](https://wirimnetz.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/anonym-im-internet-mittels-raspberry-pi-tor-und-privoxy/) is running nyx as user tor (i.e. debian-tor in Ubuntu 18.04). In this case just these 2 lines about control port needed in torrc.

```
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, running `nyx` as Tor user (it's named mostly as `tor` or `debian-tor` in a packaged binaries) has it's uses, but **only** if you're using a unix socket for a Control Protocol. The truth is that the Tor control protocol does **not** provide a fully-featured authentication system *with all the necessary  protections* like brute force defense et cetera. So, if you're operating on a machine *physically* - yes, it's OK to use tor's user. If you're connecting to the machine remotely - forget the unix socket and use the TCP port **properly encapsulated** into a really secure wrapper: STunnel with the full client and server verification with easyRSA is the easiest way, but it's secure enough to be trusted. Also keep in mind, that nyx has to be running constantly, i.e. in a screen detached terminal, so you will see actual data. If you need to collect the data and check it out from time to time - nyx is **not** a right tool: I recommend using `rrdtool` or `Zabbix` for this task - and the filesystem socket will do you good in that case.